# Can't add unique index in Laravel 11

Tags: laravel

I got an error whene I run this migration code:

```
Schema::table('badges', function (Blueprint $table) {

         $table->unique(['sede_id','prefisso', 'numero'],'unico_codice');

  });
```

Please note that I added the name of the index to avoid the "too long index name" problem.
The error is:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `badges` add unique `unico_codice`(`sede_id`, `prefisso`, `numero`))

Any clue ?

I tryed to run the SQL code manually and the unique index is created without problem.

I am running Laravel 11.0.7 with MariaDB 11.1 and PHP 8.3.4

Comment: Connection refused is problem with the DB connection. Check your `DB_HOST` is correct.

Comment: Yes DB_HOST is correct